# Quantize image (Reduce number of colors)

Tags: ios, uiimage, uicolor

I want to reduce the number of colors in an UIImageView, for example to a maximum of 16. I've tried the following approaches:

- [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) toon filter (with different quantizationLevels parameter values)
- [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) posterize filter (different colorLevels parameter values)
- Using the *"Indexed Colors"* filter in Photoshop on my source image, then importing the image into my app

However, when I look at the RGB values of the resulting pixels I seem to get a result with many more colors, with slight shades of the same color, for example many different and almost identical shades of orange.

Any suggestions? I think I might be missing something about UIImage and UIImageView that increases the number of colors again..

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm also stuck

Comment: Any ideas so far?